# Google Maps. Create numerous infoWindow with PHP variables in an efficient way

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a lot of contact details.

es:

```
<?php
$contactName1 = "Contact name number 1";
$contactName2 = "Contact name number 2";
....
?>
```

I would like to pass these variables in Javascript and create their relative infoWindow in an efficient way. Right now my code is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var initialize = function() {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.0000, 9.0000);
      var marker1pos = new google.maps.LatLng(45.1111, 9.1111);
      var marker2pos = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2222, 9.2222);

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mappa'), options);
      map.setOptions({styles: stylesArray });

      var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({position: marker1pos, map: map, flat: true});
      var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: marker2pos, map: map, flat: true});

      var content1 = '<div class="infoMap"><h2><?php echo $contactName1; ?></h2></div>';
      var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content1});
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() { infowindow1.open(map,marker1); });

      var content2 = '<div class="infoMap"><h2><?php echo $contactName2; ?></h2></div>';
      var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content2});
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() { infowindow2.open(map,marker2); });

      }
      window.onload = initialize;
  </script>
```

When the number  of the contacts is large, write and maintain the code becomes difficult.

Do you know any efficient way to do this? Maybe with some statement like foreach in PHP...

Thank you all in advance!

Alessandro

Comment: Use array for this. See answer from @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead of single vars:

```
$contactName1
$contactName2
```

To

```
$contactNames[0]
$contactNames[1]
```

Example

```
<?php foreach ($contactNames as $index => $contactName): ?>
var marker<?php echo $index; ?>pos = new google.maps.LatLng(45.1111, 9.1111);
var marker<?php echo $index; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({position: marker<?php echo $index; ?>pos, map: map, flat: true});
<!-------->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using JSON.
Once you pass the jSON data to javascript, you can access it easily.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var initialize = function() {

      <?php  
           //generate json object
           $jsonObj = ...
           echo "var javascript_json_object=".jsonObj;
      ?>
      //use javascript to access the javascript_json_object variable

      window.onload = initialize;
  </script>
```

Comment: `echo "var javascript_json_object=" . $jsonObj;` :-)

Comment: @DanFromGermany have been quite sometime i didn't write php :P .. thx .. hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Fetch contact from php loop db or json

```
 for($i=1;$i<12;$i++){ 
 $map_contactdetails.="var content1 = '<div class='infoMap'><h2>".$contactName1."</h2></div>';
    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content1});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() { infowindow1.open(map,marker1); });";    


      }
```

And inside script you can call that varable

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php echo $map_contactdetails; ?>
</script>
```